# HTML5 API file : handle live update of an input ASCII file

Tags: html, file, webgl, auto-update

I get an ASCII input file (which contains x, y, z coordinates of points) with the API File. I transform data into an array in order to display the points with Webgl. 
The question is : is it possible to load easily new contents of the ASCII file ? I use reading file function :

```
    function readingFile(evt)
{
    var f = evt.target.files[0];
    if (f) 
    {
        var r = new FileReader();
        r.onload = function(e) 
        { 
            var contents = e.target.result;
            alert( "Got the file.n" 
                +"name: " + f.name + "n"
                +"type: " + f.type + "n"
                +"size: " + f.size + " bytesn"
                + "starts with: " + contents.substr(1, contents.indexOf("n")));  

            alert('Contenu du fichier :\n\n' + contents);
            traitement(contents);
            animate();

        }
        r.readAsText(f);
    }
    else 
    { 
        alert("Failed to load file");
    }
}

document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readingFile, false);
```

Comment: Which is exactly your problem? The code you posted does not work? Do you receive any error when executing it?

Comment: The code works until the input file is not updated. If the input file is updated with new lines, those new data are not taken into account. So my problem is to handle with an event (?) the modification of the ASCII file and to get only new data. Is it more clear ?

Comment: Do you have any idea ?

Comment: The change event of the input type file element will only fire if you change the file, it will not fire when data inside the file is changed nor if it's size or modification date change. This is because input type file is designed to upload files to the server, where the important thing is the file, not it's content as If you change the content of the file, when you upload it the last version will remain on the server. Here you are using it to read the content of the file, but you cannot fire a browser event depending on an external file behaviour.

Comment: Thank you Bardo, I understand. I'm trying something else : make a loop to get new data of my input file. It works, I can udate geometry.vertices (webgl and three.js) with new data. But unfortunately I can't figure out how to display new data, but that will be another post I think, thanks again